# Set equal height

Tags: jquery

I want to set equal height for columns inside each my .block div I use each function to make it works individually but somehow it set equal height for all my div. This is the code, please help me. I only want 2 columns in each block has same height, not all columns. Thanks

```
//block1
<div class="block">
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
</div>
enter code here

//block2
<div class="block">
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
</div>

js 
$.fn.equalizeHeights = function () {
   return this.height(Math.max.apply(this, this.map(function () {
     return $(this).outerHeight(true);
   })));
};

var block = jQuery('.block');
block.each(function() {
  var columns = jQuery(this).find('.column');
  columns.equalizeHeights(); 
});
```

Comment: Your function find every .block and equalize their heights.

Comment: Hi, I thought each function will make them run individually for each block? is there anyway I can adjust js not add more class??

Comment: you got any styles to go along with these so we can see how your heights are supposed to be equalized? empty divs.. no styles.. no visuals.. what's the goal here?

Comment: Can you give the stylesheet?

Comment: @Hello Rick, please don't get me wrong, I use equalizeHeights() to apply css height for 2 columns with the bigger number in each block. So the block1 columns have same height with eachother but are different from columns in block2 eventhough I'm using 'each function'. That's something I do not understand and want to find out. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the light of the above information as it doesn't give any stylesheets you can solve your problem by

```
//block1
<div id="bloc1" class="block">
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
</div>
enter code here

//block2
<div id="block2" class="block">
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$.fn.equalizeHeights = function () {
   return this.height(Math.max.apply(this, this.map(function () {
     return $(this).outerHeight(true);
   })));
};
//for block1
var block = jQuery('#block1');
block.each(function() {
  var columns = jQuery(this).find('.column');
  columns.equalizeHeights(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take the dot out of the class name in your html -

```
<div class=".block">
```

should be

```
<div class="block">
```

Comment: Thanks I misstyped